# Checking width and setting width inside forEach loop performance

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing

I have two pieces of code below

**Snippet#1**

```
const doubleWidth = (element) => {
  const width = element.offsetWidth;
  element.style.width = `${width * 2}px`;
};
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  boxes.forEach(doubleWidth);
});
```

**Snippet#2**

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  var widths = boxes.map(item => item.offsetWidth);
  boxes.forEach((element, index) => {
         element.style.width = `${widths[index] * 2}px`;
  });
});
```

Snippet #1 has a lot 48ms compared to snippet #2 which is only 18.4ms. Why is that behaviour?

After all, I am still doing two operation of calculating and settings ( which forcers reflows ) each.

**Here's the complete code** - https://codepen.io/kushalmahajan/pen/mjXVqp?editors=0010

**Update** - So , let me explain a bit more

In Snippet #1, I see each time a pattern like calculate, Reset, Calculate, Reset ...so forth

In Snippet #2. That's not the case.

**Please base you answers around render pipeline please**

Comment: Interesting, looks like the difference is accessing the DOM element in read and write (tested with chrome)

Comment: Reading `offsetWidth` after changing CSS properties will force a reflow. So read all of them, then set all of them, instead of doing it alternatingly. Or don't read from `offsetWidth` at all and just double the pixel value that was stored in `.style.width`

Answer (score 0):

in Snippet 1 
each time you are executing 2 commands:

```
const width = element.offsetWidth;
element.style.width = `${width * 2}px`;
```

while in Snippet 2
each time you are executing only 1 command:

```
element.style.width = `${widths[index] * 2}px`;
```

Therefore  I think it's natural to have more than double the time for the execution. depending on how much time it take to execute the following command:

```
const width = element.offsetWidth;
```

For a fair comparison between the 2 snippets I would suggest removing the above command from the loop and check how long it would take to execute snippet 1 in that case.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've changed Snippet 1 to `element.style.width = \`${element.offsetWidth * 2}px\`;` and it's still much slower https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqvOQM?editors=1011

Comment: I think it's the calculation of the variable: doubleWidth that is calculated and reset each time, and this why it doesn't show in snippet 2, this calculation and resetting might also be time consuming.

Comment: Both operations are of constant time complexity. I don't think that makes a difference

Comment: in both snippets it's calculated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reason, but apparently if you store `offsetWidth` first, it doesn't matter performance-wise whether you use `forEach` or `map`: [here's a pen to illustrate this behavior](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjeqYR?editors=1011).

You can see that I timed three combinations:

1. `forEach` with immediately getting `offsetWidth` and setting `width`
2. `forEach` with storing `offsetWidth` and the corresponding element first and then setting width it in a second `forEach`
3. `map` with storing `offsetWidth` and then setting `width` on the elements in a `forEach` loop

Option *2.* an *3.* were basically the same performance wise. Judging from that, I would say that the combination of getting `offsetWidth` and setting `width` is a performance bottleneck. Can't really tell you much more than that, sorry!

---

```
window.onload = () => {
    const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box'));

    document.getElementById('double-sizes-forEach')
    .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.time('Double Sizes ForEach');

        boxes.forEach((element, index) => {
        const width = element.offsetWidth;
        element.style.width = `${width * 2}px`;
        });

        console.timeEnd('Double Sizes ForEach');
    });

    document.getElementById('double-sizes-forEach-2')
    .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.time('Double Sizes ForEach 2');

        let a = [];
        boxes.forEach((element, index) => {
        a.push([element, element.offsetWidth]);
        });
        a.forEach(([e, w]) => {
        e.style.width = `${w * 2}px`; 
        });

        console.timeEnd('Double Sizes ForEach 2');
    });

    document.getElementById('double-sizes-map')
    .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.time('Double Sizes Map');

        var widths = boxes.map(item => item.offsetWidth);
        boxes.forEach((element, index) => {
            element.style.width = `${widths[index] * 2}px`;
        });

        console.timeEnd('Double Sizes Map');
    });
};
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Double Sizes ForEach: 12.341064453125ms
Double Sizes ForEach 2: 0.539794921875ms
Double Sizes Map: 0.590087890625ms
```

---

**NOTES:**

- [what forces layout/reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)
- [article on layout performance issues and layout thrashing](http://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/)

The second article argues that you should always separate changing style (e.g. setting `width`) and taking measurements (e.g. getting `offsetWidth`) to avoid **layout thrashing**. Seems that's the problem in your code as well.

Comment: `I'm not sure about the reason, but apparently if you store offsetWidth first, it doesn't matter performance-wise whether you use forEach or map`. Oh no. I m not pointing guns at `forLoop` or `map`. Just looking for that reason only for time difference.

Comment: @kushalvm I see! Anyway, it seems like getting `offsetWidth` and then setting `width` immediately seems to be the problem. If you split getting and setting, it's much faster. The reason for that probably has to do with DOM implementation internals rather than JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes. I know that and that's maybe my question is about - Internal working of engine and hence the performance diff which comes out - in case it boils down to it

Comment: Thanks. I will dig deeper I guess.

Comment: I've added some links which might be helpful.