# Performance benchmarking of function wrapper over class vs only constructor call invocation and HaveSameMap

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, v8

I did some performance measure with CODE A and CODE B and would like to know why exactly does V8 outputs so.

**Code A**

```
const makePoint = () => {
  class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  }

  return new Point(1, 2);
}

const a = makePoint();
const b = makePoint();

console.log(%HaveSameMap(a, b)); // false
```

**First Question**, why in the world HaveSameMap returns false. I believe that both a and b are having same shape and going through same process. So why would they be different?

**Code B**

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
 }
 var a = new Point();
 var b = new Point();
```

**Second question** - Comparing performance time of both these have substantial diff. I just want to understand the underlying of type systems of V8. Why it would behave so. Calling `new Point()` vs  returning it inside `makePoint()` function. What's going on here ?

**Update - TEST METHODOLOGY**

I am testing the same via external package

and my test code looks like

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

performance.mark('start');

while (iterations--) {
  makePoint();
}

performance.mark('end');

performance.measure('My Special Benchmark', 'start', 'end');
```

Comment: How are you testing the performance? Are you retrying the tests a few hundred or thousand times, to get a mean? Did you run one before the other, but in the same code file - JIT could modify your values. Please outline your performance testing methodology.

Comment: I think the 2 questions should be separated int0 2 Stack Overflow questions and not conflated.

Comment: Yes. I am just running a while loop many times.I will update same in the question

Comment: As good programmers, we should code redundancy. Hence one code and two questions. Haha. It's interlinked anyway

Comment: I would suggest that you are breaking the Single Responsibility rule from SOLID :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, you were not only creating the instance in `makePoint` but also the `class Point` itself. Every time you called `makePoint()`, you made a new class:

```
console.log(makePoint().constructor === makePoint().constructor) // false
```

I think you are looking for

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
const makePoint = () => new Point(1, 2);
const a = makePoint();
const b = makePoint();

console.log(%HaveSameMap(a, b)); // true
console.log(a.constructor == b.constructor, a.constructor == Point); // true, true
```

Comment: This is what I looked for.

Comment: Can you also please look at this question of mine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609846/checking-width-and-setting-width-inside-foreach-loop-performance#51610687

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new `Point` class on every call to `makePoint`. This might become a bit more obvious when you directly return the class:

```
const makePoint = (x, y) => {
  class Point {...};
  return Point;
}
```

A class is create every time the class literal is evaluated. You can somewhat see this happening when adding a `console.log` right before the class definition. In your case that is evaluated every time.

Similarly, creating a new class each time is more costly that simply re-using the same class. V8 has to create a lot of internal data structures to support fast instance creation. Using a class a single time defeats this very common patter which is the slowdown you see.

Comment: That's wonderful explanation but again was more confused over Shape/Hashmaps. You definitely cleared my second point better. +1'ed.